# How can I switch to an open tab in Safari using osascript?

Tags: terminal, safari, applescript

Trying to switch tabs in Safari with `osascript`. I have tried multiple versions of the following:

```
osascript -e 'tell Application "Safari"' -e 'keystroke "2" using command down' -e 'end tell
```

Tried replacing "Safari" with "System Events and "2" with "-2". But nothing I do is working. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `key code 19` command, because the `keystroke "2"` command simulate the key code 84 (numeric keypad) instead of key code 19.

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 19 using command down
```

To know the key code of some key, download this application --> https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12

---

But, you do not need **GUI Scripting** to select a tab in Safari, use this script

```
tell application "Safari" to tell front window to set current tab to tab 2 -- this select the second tab
```

Comment: Thank you both of these examples work. Quick question - How would it be phrased if the command uses 2 or more keyboard modifiers like command and alt at the same time?

Comment: Never mind I got it. In case anyone else needs this its `osascript -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code "19"  using {option down, command down}' -e 'end tell'` Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Seamus, you do not need to use `-e 'end tell'` when the `tell` statement in in the `to` form.  In other words `tell application "AppName" to ...` negates the need for an `end tell`.

Answer (score 1):

It's System Events that handles the *keystrokes*.

In normal AppleScript the *code* would look like:

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    delay 0.5
    tell application "System Events"
        key code 19 using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

As an `osascript` command line, it would be:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate' -e 'delay 0.5' -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 19 using command down'
```

The `osascript` command line from above shown below as multiple lines for clarity:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to activate' \
          -e 'delay 0.5' \
          -e 'tell application "System Events" to key code 19 using command down'
```

**Notes:** Before telling System Events to *keystroke*, the *target* of the *keystroke* must have focus. So first, Safari must be made the frontmost window with `activate`. You must then allow a moment for it to have focus before the *keypress* and that is done with `delay 0.5` and the value of `delay` may need to be adjusted in *seconds* and or *decimal fractions* thereof. So once Safari is the frontmost window, then System Events can issue the *keystrokes*.

*This of course assumes Safari is already open with at least one window having two tabs!*

The *keystroke* used herein with Safari is a Safari 9 (El Capitan) keyboard shortcut as shown in: [Safari 9 (El Capitan): Safari keyboard and other shortcuts](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21483?locale=en_US)

> Select one of your first nine tabs      Command-1 to Command-9

Comment: This isn't working for me. It works if I manually press Cmd 2 but otherwise it just stays on the same tab after safari activates. I tried delaying for 4.0 and still nothing.

Comment: You need to allow setting the tab via cmd-number in settings of safari under the `tabs` setting

Comment: I've done that. If I manually push it on the keyboard it works fine. But nothing happens with the script.

Comment: @Seamus, I'm not sitting at a system that's running OS X 10.11 and Safari 9 to test this however later today I can test this under OS X 10.11. This works under OS X 10.8.5 when substituting the appropriate keystroke and I assumed the same paradigm would work, sorry.  Also the `delay` doesn't need to be 4.0 and typically 1 second of fraction thereof is adequate.

Comment: I appreciate your help. Yeah the 4 second delay was overkill but I just thought I'd try it to rule out the possibility. It is strange. It works just fine using the same format with letter presses like `'keystroke "a" using command down'` so I don't see why this would be any different.

Comment: Just to add for the sake of clarity: I am using Safari 9.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.4. as well as Bash 4.3.